# how to clip an image and make it responsive as well?

Tags: css, svg, path, responsive

I am not sure how to do the clipping of image and have it responsive as well.
till now, I was using svg like this and it does work but it is not responsive.
okay, here's a demo of what's happening at the moment.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vq4wx2y367
here's the code

```
 <img  src={require('./assets/fans.jpg')} alt='projectvoice' className='fans' />
            <svg width="0" height="0">
                <defs>
                    <clipPath id="myClip">    

                    <path d="M-20,150 a1,1 0 0,1 100,0" fill="blue" />

  <path d="M50,150 a5,5 0 0,1 210,0" fill="red" />

                    </clipPath> 


                </defs>
                </svg>
```

I have also tried using the circle command like this

```
  <img src="http://maddesigns.de/SVG/clip-path-test_files/clouds.jpg" />
            <svg width="0" height="0">
              <defs>
                <clipPath id="myClip">
                  <circle cx="160" cy="280" r="180" />
                  <circle cx="325" cy="280" r="275" />
                </clipPath>
              </defs>
            </svg>
```

I am using a layout here where when the screen is bigger, say on laptop, then 2 columns appear side by side.
and the right side column has the image like this

[image]

but when it shows up on mobile, there are 2 columns which show up one under another and the image takes the full row

it should show up something like this
[image]
 and that's where it's not working.

it doesnt show up like that and doesnt even align properly

I have been trying to use svg but if there's something else that could help too, then I am ready to go that way.

please give some ideas of how to make this happen.

okay, here's a demo of what's happening at the moment.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vq4wx2y367
In situation 1, when 2 columns are side by side, then the image doesnt look like the one I have shown above for that situation.
it's a very small image  then and I want to be touching the bottom and the right side of the div.

and in situation 2, it is kind of looking like that, but it's not taking up the whole space there is in that div. in this case it should be touching the right and left side borders and also be touching the bottom of the div.

Comment: Can you demo this?

Comment: The following expressions are vague (as in they might mean something different for each person reading them and therefore are not objectively quantifiable or measurable): *"align properly"*, *"not working"* (when referring to display and positioning). At this point, it is unclear what the expected result is on each responsiveness interval. Could you please clarify? If you don't know how to describe technically the desired result in a way that cannot be misinterpreted, using images might help.

Comment: Have added the demo and explained what I meant

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this covers every aspect you need, but I would probably just wrap the image in a container and clip it with overflow. You can play around with that until it fits your layouting:

```css
.img-clip {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-clip img {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .img-clip {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .img-clip img {
    padding-left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-clip">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe7zl.png" alt='projectvoice' className='fans' />
</div>
```

Comment: my image is in the image of a rectangle at the moment and i want to using clipping or svg to make it into the 2 shapes i have shown above. 2 different images shown above for 2 different sizes.